# Какие знания в питоне нужны, чтобы работать с PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

Программирование на школьном уровне скорее. Классы не изучала, но мне показалось что умение с ними работать как раз и необходимо для работы с PyQt.

Comment: Что такое школьный уровень? Да это и не имеет значения - главное желание и все придет. Если особого желания нет, то не теряйте зря время )

Answer (score 0):

Не является полным ответом на вопрос, так как не знаю PyQt:-)
Но, полагаю, важным сказать, что изучение языка в очень узких пределах - практика опасная. В решающий момент можно понять, что знаний нет и быстро не набрать. Python поддерживает функциональную и ООП ("классы") парадигмы, знать надо обе.

Ниже моё личное мнение, что надо знать в целом (Python изучаю недавно, на C программировал профессионально). Надеюсь, профессионалы в Python дадут свой ответ с учётом их опыта и непосредственно PyQt.

**Кроме обеих парадигм надо хорошо знать:**

встроенные типы данных,

синтаксис, операторы,  управляющие конструкции,

функции и области видимости, рекурсии,

генераторы, декораторы,

методы отладки.

**Надо знать хоть немного:**

как объекты размещаются в памяти,

как работает GIL,

модули и пакеты (import и т.д.),

исключения (Exception),

потоки, процессы, асинхронное программирование,

автоматизированное тестирование.

Comment: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Answer (score 0):

> Какие знания в питоне нужны, чтобы работать с PyQt?
> Ну тут все зависит от того что именно ты хочешь добиться, и какая цель.

Классы изучать нужно потому что это сильный и полезный инструмент. И он нужен чтобы куда-то да двигаться.

Проблема твоя в скорее всего в том что PyQt это очень большой и мощный фраемворк, с многолетней историей развитием, от того это своего рода как будто отдельный язык программирования, со своими тонкостями, просто на привычном тебе синтаксисе и сборщике. Там есть свои типы, свой внутренний EventLoop в классе QApplication и.т.д.

Но если по вопросу, то да тебе нужно понимать в классах что это такое, как и с чем это едят, наследование, инкапсуляцию, полиморфизм, даже возможно какие-то паттерны проектирования по типу Observer, Decorator.